# More sort column in JHipster

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jhipster

I try to configure sort column using the rout.ts file of my entity.

In the "data" tag I put `defaultSort: ['firstCol,desc','secondCol,asc'],` but I gave an error.

Then I put all in a single String `defaultSort: 'firstCol,desc,secondCol,asc',` but the secondCol is not considered the the query sent to microservice

Then I put all in a single String using a char separator like ";" `'firstCol,desc;secondCol,asc'` but nothing! The secondCol is not considered.

I try to debug and see the ng-jhipster.js?064b file and see:

```js
parsePredicate(sort) {
        return sort.split(',')[0].split('%2C')[0];
    }
```

It seems the only first parameter is passed (as I see effectively). Is there any other way to pass one other sort column (pass 2 columns in the same time).

I see Spring data rest accept more column simply append another sort column in the request: `?sort=name,asc&sort=numberOfHands,desc`.

How can send this in jhipster???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved myself putting the sort column not in defaultSort of "data" tag, but specify the sort predicate in sort method if .component.ts